# Logic and implication negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am new to predicate logic and there is something I can't seem to understand.

Let's have an implication:
If I have a sister, I have a sibling.

Now, it's negation should be:
I have a sister and I do not have a sibling.

But I can't understand why the following is not a valid negation:
If I have a sister, I do not have a sibling.

It should be a negation because the first part of the implication happened and the second did not.

Comment: "I have a sister, but I do not have a sibling" is true, does not imply "if I have a sister, I do not have a sibling" is true.

Comment: The [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) is not equivalent to the [indicative conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicative_conditional).

Comment: @SenZen but I does, doesn't it? If we have a statement "If I have a sister, I do not have a sibling" and I, for example, have a sister and I don't have a sibling, then by filling the truth table of the former statement, we get a truth. I have a sister, so the first part of the statement is true. I do not have a sibling, so the second part is also true. And 1-->1 means that it is true

Comment: @ampersander The model holds for a single person, but falls apart when you have multiple. What if I have a sister, but not a sibling, but Bob has a sister and has a sibling? Then "If I have a sister, I do not have a sibling" is false because it fails for Bob.

Comment: @ampersander, The material conditional doesn't exactly translate over to the usage of if $X$ then $Y$ in natural language as one would expect. I don't have a sister so for me, $P$ is false, however the material conditional $P\to Q$, in this case is true, irrespective of me having a sibling or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement $\neg A$ is the negation of a statement $A$ if and only if whenever $A$ is true, $\neg A$ is false and whenever $A$ is false, $\neg A$ is true. So to find out which is the negation of the original statement, you just need to investigate all the possible cases and verify that the two statements have "opposite" truth values.

Remember that "If $A$ then $B$" is true whenever $A$ is false or $B$ is true -- that's just how material implication is defined. The problem is the former case: When "I have a sister" is false, then "If I have a sister, I have a sibling" and "If I have a sister, I don't have a sibling" are both true, so they do not have opposing truth values in all cases.

In contrast, "I have a sister and I don't have a sibling" is false whenever "If I have a sister, I have a sibling" is true (namely in those cases wher "I have a sister" is false or "I have a sibling" is true), and "I have a sister and I don't have a sibling" is true whenever "If I have a sister, I have a sibling" is false (namely in that case when "I have a sister" is true but "I have a sibling" false), as you can easily verify with a truth table.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$P\rightarrow Q\equiv\lnot P\lor Q$$
Here's how to properly negate the above statement
$$\lnot(P\rightarrow Q)\equiv\lnot(\lnot P\lor Q)\equiv P\land\lnot Q$$
Now let me show you why the following is not a negation of the original statement
$$P\rightarrow\lnot Q\equiv\lnot P\lor\lnot Q$$
Notice that this only negates $Q$, however we are seeking to negate the whole statement.
Also note that if $P\equiv\mbox{false}$, then we have
$$P\rightarrow Q\equiv P\rightarrow\lnot Q\equiv\mbox{true}$$
Which is clearly not a negation of the original statement. I hope this helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "If I have a sister, I have a sibling" is true. However. you are negating that statement which means that the statement "I have a sister and I do not have a sibling" should be false, which holds. The statement need not be true in order for it to be a valid negation.

Comment: You mean should be true?

Comment: The first statement is taken to be true which means its negation should be false.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but I think you just repeated what the OP said without explaining the why.

Comment: I suppose my explanation might not be clear.

Answer (score -1):

The structure of your statement is $A\Rightarrow B$ where $A=\text{"I have a sister"}$ and $B=\text{"I have a sibling"}$. Then the negation is $\lnot B\Rightarrow \lnot A$ which is "If I don't have a sibling I don't have a sister".

Comment: No that's contrapositive.

Comment: You're right, the negation would be $\lnot B \wedge A$ which is "I do not have a sibling and I have a sister".